# Reduced nonintegral domain contains at least two minimal primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let R be a ring such that R is reduced and R is not an integral domain. Show that R contains at least 2 minimal prime ideals.

Comment: note that R is a commutative ring with unity

Comment: Geometrically, this comes from the fact that a scheme is integral if and only if it is reduced and irreducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is immediate once you know that the nilradical of $R$ is the intersection of its minimal primes.

Comment: is the intersection of primes ideal equal the intersection of minimal prime ideals?!

Comment: @nesreen Clearly any non-minimal prime ideal contributes noting to the intersection.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmm, I understand now, thans